# In Golden Calf tragedy, who was hit with Heavenly plague?

Tags: avodah-zarah, beit-din-court, capital-punishment, golden-calf-egel

Th the aftermath of the Golden Calf there were two rounds of executions: the massacre of 3000 fellow Jews and the Heavenly plague:

> "וַיַּעֲשׂוּ בְנֵי־לֵוִי כִּדְבַר מֹשֶׁה וַיִּפֹּל מִן־הָעָם בַּיּוֹם הַהוּא כִּשְׁלֹשֶׁת אַלְפֵי אִישׁ׃...
> "וַיִּגֹּף ה' אֶת־הָעָם עַל אֲשֶׁר עָשׂוּ אֶת־הָעֵגֶל אֲשֶׁר עָשָׂה אַהֲרֹן׃"
> The Levites did as Moses had bidden, and some three thousand of the people fell that day... Then the LORD sent a plague upon the people, for what they did with the calf that Aaron made." [Exodus.32.35](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.32.35?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=he)

Who was executed with the plague (Rashi - Heavenly death) and for what?

Comment: This is a hard one to answer as the episode is difficult to quantify. See Ramban https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.32.35?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Ramban_on_Exodus.32.35.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en and others who pick up on the theme that the Torah expressly doesn't mention how many died (or not that much else for that matter)

Comment: I understand it as referring to the 3000 people killed above (נגף doesn't have to mean plague, as in Ex 21:22, Lev 26:17, Num 14:42, Judg 20:35, Sam 1:4:2, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rashi explains the three categories of punishments.

[Ki Sisa 32:20](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9893/showrashi/true#v20)

> Then he took the calf they had made, burned it in fire, ground it to
> fine powder, scattered [it] upon the surface of the water, and gave
> [it to] the children of Israel to drink.

**RASHI**

> **and gave [it to] the children of Israel to drink:** He intended to test them like women suspected of adultery [are tested, as prescribed
> in Num. 5:11-31] (A.Z. 44a). Three [different] death penalties were
> meted out there: (1) If there were witnesses [to the worship] and
> warning [had been issued to the sinners, they were punished] by the
> sword, according to the law (Deut. 13:13-18) that applies to the
> people of a city that has been led astray who are many [people
> involved]. (2) [Those who practiced idolatry with] witnesses but
> without warning [died] from a plague, as it is said: “Then the Lord
> struck the people with a plague” (verse 35). (3) [Those who practiced
> idolatry both] without witnesses and without warning [died] from
> dropsy, for the water tested them and their stomachs swelled up (Yoma
> 66b).

Answer (score 1):

See my [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/126010/18471) to your related question. According to one opinion, they were the ones who worshipped the Calf and were observed by witnesses, but weren't warned; according to the other, they were the ones who were happy about what was going on, but didn't actually worship or adore the Calf.